# Projective objects for compact po-spaces

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, boolean-algebras

Let us consider the following definition: a compact po-space is a pair $(X,\leq)$ where $X$ is a compact space and $\leq$ is an order, closed on $X^2$. Then, we can consider the category $KPoSp$ whose objects are compact po-spaces and whose morphisms are increasing continuous functions.

Moreover, let us denote by $KHaus$ the category of compact Hausdorff spaces with continuous functions.

It is known that the projective objects in $KHaus$ are  the compact Hausdorff spaces which are **extremally disconnected**, in the sense that the closure of an open set is also open. (I have it from section 7 of *Stone duality and Gleason covers through de Vries duality*).

I would like to know if there is somewhere a similar result for the category $KPoSp$ ?

Comment: Are the objects of $KPoSp$ assumed to be Hausdorff? If not, I'd think one should first ask what are the projective objects in the category of compact (not-necessarily-Hausdorff) spaces. Also, what exactly is meant by "projective"? Probably you mean "object which has the left lifting property with respect to certain maps", but which maps? Surjections? Epimorphisms? Quotient maps? Finally, is $\leq$ assumed to be a poset structure or just a preorder?

Comment: For the definition of "projective", I must admit I don't know the kind of map I'm looking for (surjective maps would be perfect, but I can be satisfied with epimorphisms). The objects of $KPoSp$ are indeed Hausdorff. This is a consequence of $\leq$ closed. Finally, yes we have a poset structure (the relation between compact po-spaces and Priestley spaces is similar to the one between compact Hausdorff and Stone spaces, if it can help.)

Comment: Presumably you want to first show every compact pospace is a quotient of a Priestley space and then look at injective distributive lattices.  Did you look in Johnstone's stone spaces or the compendium of continuous lattices?

Comment: I suspect that surjections are not what you want -- they lead to "too few" projective objects (and epimorphisms will be, if anything, worse in this regard). For instance, for $P$ to have the left lifting property against the bijection $f: \{0,1\} \to \{0 < 1\}$ (where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete ordering) is a very strong requirement. In particular, if $P$ is totally disconnected and has the left lifting property with respect to $f$, then I believe the order on $P$ must be discrete. So perhaps you want "projective" to mean the left lifting property with respect to quotient maps.

Comment: On the other hand, I'm not sure I'd expect there to be a well-behaved notion of "projective" even in the category $Pos$ of posets without a topology -- generally I expect "projective" to be well-behaved in "algebraic" categories (by which I mean roughly: monadic over $Set$ or monadic over $Set^S$ for some set $S$), which $Pos$ is not. Analogously, I don't think there's a good notion of "projective object" in the category $Cat$ of categories.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg . Yes, I would like something like that. I have yet to look in Johnstone or in the compendium.

Comment: @TimCampion, you are presumably right. Again, I'm not still not sure about the property I'm really looking for. From "Proximity frames and regularisation", it seems to me that we can have a  result "similar" to the one I mentioned in my original post. The problem is now that I still have to determine what "similar" means. The projective property on compact Hausdorff may have an equivalent characterisation and this is this latter equivalent characterisation which will be nicely generalised. This why I wanted to know if someone already explored this problem.